# Avoid to reload ajax content

Tags: jquery, ajax, hash

I use ajax to load html page inside a div container.
The html content is loaded on element click like this :

```
$(".link").click(function () {
    $('.link').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
    ajaxify($(this).attr('href'));
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
    return false;
});
```

I want to avoid to reload the content if the url hash in the internet browser is the same as the `$(".link").attr("href")`. 
So when I click the same element again, I want that nothing happen.

Currently, if I click again on the same element,  the same content is loaded with the ajax call.

Loïc

Comment: What does `ajaxify()` do? Is that function from a library, or something you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Change the selector from `$(".link")` to `$(".link:not(.current)")`, so your click handler will only be called on links that are don't have the class `current`.

Update: That doesn't work, because jQuery assigns the click function to all links on document.ready (or wherever this code will be executed) and doesn't check the selector on click. So you need to check for the class `current` in the click handler, like so:

```
$(".link").click(function () {
  if($(this).hasClass('current')) return false;
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the `window.location` object (or simply `location` if `window` is the current scope) and compare it to the `href` property of your link.

```
$(".link").click(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('href') != location.href) {
      $('.link').removeClass('current');
      $(this).addClass('current');
      ajaxify($(this).attr('href'));
      window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
      return false;
    }
});
```

If your link is a relative path, you could use `location.pathname` instead of `location.href`

Comment: Thank you. I tried this code but it don't works. The content is still reloaded. I just precise that the href doesn't have hash and the browser url add a hash in my ajax content loader.

Comment: please put a console.log($(this).attr('href')) example

Comment: Thanks but the problem was solved with this : $('.link').click(function () {
    var link = $(this);
    if (!link.hasClass('current')) {
        $('.link').removeClass('current');
        link.addClass('current');
        ajaxify(link.attr('href'));
        window.location.hash = link.attr("href");
    }
    return false;
});

Answer (score 0):

You could use the fact that you add the "current" class to the selected link to conditionally execute the code in the handler, like this:

```
$('.link').click(function () {
    var link = $(this);
    if (!link.hasClass('current')) {
        $('.link').removeClass('current');
        link.addClass('current');
        ajaxify(link.attr('href'));
        window.location.hash = link.attr("href");
    }
    return false;
});
```